# how to sum binary results up in r

Tags: r

I am new to R and still learning. 
I have a dataset like this

```
county chemicalA chemicalB chemicalC chemicalD
A           1       0          1         0
B           0       0          0         0
C           1       0          0         0
D           0       1          1         0
```

I generate these binary variables by using code:

```
chemicalA=ifelse(Mean.Value_chemicalA>0,1,0)
chemicalA[is.na(chemicalA)]=0
```

Now I would like to sum the "1" up and see how many chemicals are detected in one place.My ideal result is like this:

```
county chemicalA chemicalB chemicalC chemicalD   detection
A           1       0          1         0           2
B           0       0          0         0           0
C           1       0          0         0           1
D           0       1          1         1           3
```

I have tried

```
data$detection=chemicalA+chemicalB+chemicalC+chemicalD
```

But the result is only 2 and 0 and I don't know why. At first, I thought the chemicalX might not be numeric data and I used `class()`. All the chemicalX variables return as `numeric`.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `rowSums(df1[startsWith(names(df1), "chemical")])`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` on the column names that `startsWith` the prefix 'chemical'

```
data$detection <- rowSums(data[startsWith(names(data), "chemical")])
```

Comment: I am sorry that I just give examples. What if the row names do not start with a prefix?

Comment: @Christina you can either use index as. in your post or the column names with `names`

Answer (score 0):

I think `rowSums` works better when the row name starts with the same prefix. But if not, we can try `apply`.

```
data$detection=apply(data[,c(1:5)], 1, sum)
```

Comment: You can use `data$detection = rowSums(data[,1:5])`